Как в шорткод добавить tooltip с html содержимым?
Есть сайт на wordpress где через шорткод добавляю всплывающую подсказку bootstrap таким образом:
function tooltip_func( $atts ){

    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        array(
           'text' => '',
           'toggle' => 'tooltip',
           'placement' => 'bottom',
           'html' => 'true'
        ), 
        $atts
    );

    $output = '';
    if ( !$attributes['text'])
        return $output; 

    $output .= '<span  data-bs-toggle="'.$attributes['toggle'].'" data-bs-html="'.$attributes['html'].'" data-bs-placement="'.$attributes['placement'].'" data-bs-title="'.html_entity_decode($attributes['text']).'"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'tooltip', 'tooltip_func' );

Теперь мне нужно добавить ссылку внутрь tooltip применяя разметку html. Как видно ниже в чистом bootstrap это возможно сделать
Код


var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" title="Текст <a href='https://youtube.com'>Ссылка</a> текст">
  Tooltip with HTML
</button>



Но, если добавляю через щорткод вот так
[tooltip text='Текст <a href="https://youtube.com">Ссылка</a> текст' icon='fa-info-circle']
то получаю сломанную верстку. Пробовал делать экранирование кавычек и кодирование контента, но не помогло..
Как грамотно решить данную задачу?

Ура! Я разобрался как нажать ссылку)) нужно навести на кнопку и нажать ПКМ, пока висит окошко, тултип будет заблокирован и не исчезнет, либо просто клик по кнопке заблокирует)) пользуйтесь (c)

@Jour а что-нибудь по существу готовы предложить?

без опытов на реальном коде, по существу - можно сказать только если был подобный опыт, не мой случай) а так без запущенного проекта и консоли трудно что-то предполагать) вы возможно не так поняли мой комментарий)

Сработала история поменять кавычки в шорткоде местами, т.е. вместо
[tooltip text='Текст <a href="https://youtube.com">Ссылка</a> текст' icon='fa-info-circle']
вот так:
[tooltip text="Текст <a href='https://youtube.com'>Ссылка</a> текст" icon="fa-info-circle"]
Причем, обнаружил баг (фичу) в редакторе, что при переключении с вида html на визуальный редактор, кавычки возвращаются на исходные. Не понимаю почему
